# Thinkpad T400 wireless drops connection randomly

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, thinkpad

Thinkpad T400, Ubuntu 10.04, not dual-booting with Windows so any Windows-based solutions are out of the question.

I have tried disabling the N part of the wifi driver but that didn't work. It connects and then drops the connection a few minutes later.

I have checked the power management settings and there doesn't seem to be anything obvious that could be linked to it.

Comment: Does this happen on ANY wireless network, or only one?

Comment: Don't know if you can call this common, but here are 35 posts at the lenovo forums http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?q=t400+drops+wireless+connection regarding this exact problem with this model series.  No solution exists from Lenovo, and "fixes" range from none, to replacing the wireless card, to replacing routers (seriously?).  What conclusion did **you** come to after reading those posts?

Comment: I'm thinking BIOS setting.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but can be helpfull ...

So, in case of wireless card replacement, you must use an approved card because BIOS will check it.

If you want to use an alternate card, your have to replace BIOS by an alternate one, instructions are on http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/44644-Modified-BIOS-Needed-Lenovo-T400-BIOS-Versiob-7UET94WW